# Save list as template - include content and deploy on new site

Tags: list, content, template

I am going to upload my list template onto a live site, don't have the option of testing first. Will the .stp file include the content type used by the list. Also where will it be uploaded to on the new site e.g Site Content Types or List Template Gallery or where?
I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 4):

**Question**: **Will the .stp file include the content type used by the list?**

So answer of this question is, no the content type will not be included with the list template.

**Question**: **where will it be uploaded to on the new site?**

We upload the .stp file in List Template Gallery. So, it will be stored there in certain. and then you can create a new list from this list template from "Add an App" option. You will find the uploaded list template here.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3):

When saving the list as a template you get the option "Include content". So depending on your selection content will be included, but I think there is a limitation regarding the max. size of list templates (which was pretty low in SP2010, I think 10 MB) I will doublecheck on that...

[image]

Comment: First addition: The template will be uploaded to list template galery.

Comment: And the content type of the list, will that also be included if i select "Include Content"??

Comment: Will the content type also be in the "List Template Gallery"?

Comment: No, the content type will not be included. And I dont think there is a way to include it in a list template. Only chance to copy the content type into another site collection would be to use the content type hub (which might introduce other challenges...)

Answer (score 0):

### Create a list template

1. Open the list that you want to save as a template.
2. Click Settings and then click List Settings.
3. In the Permissions and Management column, click Save list as template.
   The Save as Template page appears.
4. In the File Name box, type the file name to use for the template file.

   NOTE: Do not add a file extension to the file name. The .stp file extension
   is automatically added for you.
5. In the Template name box, type the title that you want to appear in the list template gallery for this template.
6. In the Template Description box, type a description for the template.
7. To include the content that is currently in this list in the new list
   template, select the Include Content check box.

   NOTES:

   This step does not save any security settings that may have been applied to
   the list. Because of this, we highly recommend that you save this list
   template to a secure place so that it cannot be restored by someone who
   should not have access to this content.

   By default, you can create a list template that contains up to 10 megabytes (MB) of content. Server administrators can increase this size limit, if necessary.

   Click OK.
8. The new list template appears in the list template gallery.

[MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)